# How to save log in file in .net core worker service?

Tags: asp.net-core, backgroundworker

nowadays, I am working on a .Net core worker service and I'd like to save my project's errors in a file (text file)
I couldn't find any settings for this

```cs
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{ 
    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

    logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings()
    {
        SourceName = "CallerTestCacheServiceCoreAPI",
        LogName = "CallerTestCacheServiceCoreAPILog",                     
    });
})
```

Comment: Try using SeriLog - https://serilog.net/

Comment: Did you check the docs ? [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). There's no built-in file provider because everyone uses one of the third-party providers listed at the end. File logging may look simple but in realilty, there are a lot of "interesting" cases, like the need to save different types of errors to different files. Some of those providers, like Serilog, support structured logging

Comment: @YanivAmrami How can I implement SeriLog in backgroundworker app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an extension method in another class like this project
https://github.com/MV10/Serilog.Dependency.Injection

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddSerilogServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    return services.AddSerilogServices(
        new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
            .WriteTo.File("log.txt")
            //.WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(), "log.txt")
            .WriteTo.Console());
}
```

and introduce it in program.cs services

```cs
services.AddSerilogServices();
```

and in my worker class:

```cs
readonly Serilog.ILogger _log;

public Worker(  Serilog.ILogger log)
{  
    _log = log;
    log.Information("Hello World!");  
}
```

and it worked

Comment: Is `text` file is getting generate for both `windows` and `linux`?

Answer (score 1):

in Main method (program class):

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

In IHostBuilder method, add the `UseSerilog()`:

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog()
```

In your controller, use DI to get the instance of the logger, add the following:

```cs
public class MyController: Controller
{
    private ILogger _logger;
    public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

To log messages, use the `_logger` instance, e.g:
`_logger.LogInformation("User {user} logged in", user_record);`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of third party providers which can handle log sinks to file if you really need that.

the serilog one if a very good example, check the readme on the below

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file

Comment: it worked. but not in my worker class. just in program.cs it's working. how can I use it in my worker class?

Comment: you can inject ILogger<T> in the constructor of your worker class.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `Serilog` logger change your `Program` class to:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                // Add your services and workers here
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            })
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, services, loggerConfiguration) =>
                loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));
}
```

In your `appsettings.json` remove the `"Logging"` section and either replace it with a `"Serilog"` section (as described [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration)) or specify the settings in code.

This answer is based on the instructions given for the asp net core sink by the `Serilog` library ([link](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore)) since the `Worker` template uses the same system of hosting as an asp net core project.